# Jinja2 gives DeprecationWarning about importing ABC from containers

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I see https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1401, but that says that the issue was closed.

I'm using python 3.7, Jinja2 2.10 and pyparsing 2.3.1. Both as upgraded as pip wants to do...

The full warning is:

```
/Users/brianp/Dropbox (CEP)/venvs/mac/CYAN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py:485
  /Users/brianp/Dropbox (CEP)/venvs/mac/CYAN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/utils.py:485: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
    from collections import MutableMapping
```

It appears that the fix was made, but never released? that seems weird:

https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/867

Comment: The traceback you posted is jinja2 code, not pyparsing - I am removing the pyparsing tag. Looking at the GitHub history, Jinja2 2.10 also includes this fix. Try uninstall/reinstall jinja2 using pip3 -U and confirm your jinja2 version is 2.10.

Comment: I added pyparsing because in the github thread, they said it was in pyparsing within jinja2...  And yes, 2.10 is the version I have installed.

Comment: If it were the pyparsing issue, the traceback would point to pyparsing.py, not jinja2/utils.py.  That particular line can be found in the jinja2 code, with a changeset removing it Aug 7, 2018 (https://github.com/pallets/jinja/commit/31bf9b7e71c3fee3b7866ffdc0f70f4525a490d9).

Comment: Hmm, so why is it still in 2.10? (I'm on a mac in case that matters)

Comment: I just pip installed jinja2 to a scratch virtualenv, and utils.py *does* include the offending import. Submit a ticket to the jinja project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue using pytest which now gives an error on every run because of these deprecation warnings, after some scouring around on the GitHub page I found something that might explain this though the latest release is `2.10.1` likely the one everybody is using. And according to the [Changelog](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/CHANGES.rst#version-2101) for version `2.10.2` includes the `Fix Python 3.7 deprecation warnings.` as this version is not released yet we will all have to wait.